# HDF5 ImportError with PyTables for Windows

Tags: python, dll, hdf5, pytables

I have installed the HDF5.dll and HDF5dll.dll in every directory I can think of--PYTHONPATH, USERPROFILE, within the PyTables site-packages folder--and I still return the following error:

```
ImportError: Could not load any of ['hdf5.dll', 'hdf5dll.dll'], please ensure that it can be found in the system path
```

Both of these are definitely within the system path and I still can't test PyTables without this message. Does anyone know how to solve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error in `Python 3.6.0 (x64)` under `Windows 10`. Anecdotally, based on `Google` searches, there are reports that tables is broken for `Python 3` since June 2017, and apparently not fixed yet.

However, I can import tables in `Python 2.7.13 (x64)` under `Windows 10`. So see if you can run your script under `Python 2.7`.

Answer (score 0):

I installed PyTables 3.5.2 from PyPI and got

*"Fail: ImportError: HDFStore requires PyTables, "Could not load any of ['hdf5.dll', 'hdf5dll.dll'], please ensure that it can be found in the system path"*

when trying to pandas.read_hdf(). Then I followed a link on https://www.pytables.org/usersguide/installation.html to Christoph Gohlkes page https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and downloaded **tables‑3.5.2‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl** from there. After a pip uninstall/install everything is working fine now. I still don't have a hdf5*.dll in my path ...

Answer (score 0):

I had no luck with the documentation and every single post I went thru. I kept getting:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'hdf5.lib'
* Using Python 3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]
* USE_PKGCONFIG: False
* Found HDF5 using system PATH ('C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\h5py')
.. ERROR:: Could not find a local HDF5 installation.
```

This did the trick, though:

> Copy hdf5.dll to
> C:\Users<user>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tables

Latest dll can be found here: https://pypi.org/project/h5py/#files:

```
pip install -U C:\downloads\h5py-3.1.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
```

I did add h5py to my Windows Path at some stage.

> Ex: C:\Users<user>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\h5py

But I can't confirm the impact of that.